# O que é uma linguagem estaticamente tipada?

Tags: terminologia, tipagem

Após ler uma afirmação de que linguagens fracamente tipadas eram ruins, fui pesquisar sobre o assunto, e acabei descobrindo o termo "estaticamente tipada".

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046246/is-there-a-statically-weak-typed-language), nessa pergunta do SO em inglês, é dito que:

> static (types are checked at compile time)

(estática (tipos são checados na hora de compilar))

Então uma linguagem estaticamente tipada pode ser considerada uma linguagem de tipagem forte? Pois não vai permitir coisas como `true == 1`. Ou eu entendi errado?

Comment: Estou acostumado a ser um contra ponto a `dynamic typing` e `duck typing`. No caso da tipagem estática, o programador diz que a variável representa um inteiro ou um objeto do tipo `X`. Muito comum em Java, como usar `int i` ou `String name`. Isso em contraponto de Python que você não declara o tipo da variável ao criá-la.

Comment: Essa pergunta tem exatamente a resposta que eu queria, obrigado @Mathias